# Notify ViewModel of Asynchronous changes in Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm relatively new to MVVM and I'm wondering about the best way to structure my application. Here is a sample of my models:

```
  public class ModelSource : ModelBase
  {
    #region Fields

    private int _isLoading;

    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    private ObservableCollection<PCDatabase> _databases;

    #endregion //Fields

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<PCDatabase>Databases
    {
        get
        {
            if (_databases == null)
            {

                _databases = new ObservableCollection<PCDatabase>();
            }
            return _databases;
        }
        set
        {
            _databases = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Databases");
        }
    }

    public int IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            _isLoading = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all Databases from the Server
    /// </summary>
    public void getDatabasesAsync(ConfigDatabaseConnection _currentConfig)
    {
      //execute SQL Query...
    }
```

(ModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Here is my corresponding ViewModel:

```
namespace DbRestore.ViewModel
{
public class ViewModelSource : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<PCDatabase> _databases;

    private ModelSource _modelSource;

    private ICommand _populateDatabaseCommand;

    public ConfigDatabaseConnection _currentConfig;

    public ViewModelSource()
    {
        this.ModelSource = new ModelSource();
    }

    #region Commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Command that opens a Database Connection Dialog 
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand OpenDataBaseConnectionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_populateDatabaseCommand == null)
            {
                _populateDatabaseCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.PopulateDatabases()
                    );
            }
            return _populateDatabaseCommand;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PCDatabase> Databases
    {
        get
        {
            return _databases;
        }

        set
        {
            _databases = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Databases");
        }
    }

    #endregion //Commands

    public void PopulateDatabases()
    {
        ModelSource.getDatabasesAsync(_currentConfig);
    }
```

Calling ModelSource.getDatabasesAsync(_currentConfig) gets my SQL Data in my model. Due to some of my SQL queries being quite complex, I've implemented a Background Worker that runs these queries asynchronously.

How do I get the data into my ViewModel, which is bound to my View? Or is my design approach as a whole faulty?

Things I've considered and tried:

- Binding directly to the model: Works, but I've been told that this is a
  bad practice, and the application logic should reside in the Model.
- Moving the SQL queries into the ViewModel: Also works, but then my Model 
  class seems to be redundant - it would be nothing but a custom datatype.
- Run the queries synchronously and directly assign the Observable 
  Collection in my model to the Observable Collection in my ViewModel. Also 
  works, but then I'm running into problems with my BackgroundWorker, 
  because the ViewModel won't know when the Query is actually finished.

Comment: Subscribe to Model `PropertyChanged`, check if it was `nameof(ModelSource.Databases)` and if it become `false` then data are loaded (?), update properties used in bindings.

Comment: About things you considered: 1) nope, View and Model shouldn't have any relationship 2) Nope, sql queries should be in a Service/DAO layer 3) Nope, Model shouldn't know ViewModel (because multiple ViewModel could use the Model). The right way is to raise an event that's catched by the ViewModel object

Comment: @Nkoniishvt: Thank you. The information you've given correlates with my findings. My problem is that I'm really green when it comes to WPF AND c#, the app I have to build is quite complex, and there's a lot of information on WPF/MVVM, some of it of quite outdated. Could you point me to a good tutorial that involves a Service/DAO Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move all your database logic into a service (aka repository) class.
2. It is OK to bind directly to the model properties instead of creating a dozen ViewModel proxy classes for each Model, as soon as you don't need any special view-related logic around a particular model. So exposing a collection of `PCDatabase` is OK.

Since you're using `BackgroundWorker`, I assume you use .NET Framework 3.5 and don't have TPL.

```
public interface IPCDatabaseRepository
{
    void GetPCDatabasesAsync(Action<IList<PCDatabase>> resultHandler);
}

public class PCDatabaseRepository : IPCDatabaseRepository
{
    public void GetPCDatabasesAsync(Action<IList<PCDatabase>> resultHandler)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Result = // Execute SQL query...
        };  

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            resultHandler(args.Result as IList<PCDatabase>);
            worker.Dispose();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

public class ViewModelSource : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IPCDatabaseRepository _databaseRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<PCDatabase> _databases;
    private bool _isBusy;

    public ViewModelSource(IPCDatabaseRepository databaseRepository /*Dependency injection goes here*/)
    {
        _databaseRepository = databaseRepository;
        LoadDatabasesCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadDatabases, () => !IsBusy);
    }

    public ICommand LoadDatabasesCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<PCDatabase> Databases
    {
        get { return _databases; }
        set { _databases = value; OnPropertyChanged("Databases"); }
    }

    public bool IsBusy 
    { 
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set { _isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy"); CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); }
    }

    public void LoadDatabases()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        _databaseRepository.GetPCDatabasesAsync(results =>
        {
            Databases = new ObservableCollection(results);
            IsBusy = false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these articles?

Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Commands
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx

These should cover a good strategy especially when working with async/await.

Comment: I've read about async/await and TPL, and I'll definitely have a look at these articles. So far I've stuck with Background Worker because that seemed to be quite easy to implement.